# MVC Jquery unresponsive after partial update

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

On my page I have a button for delete and that triggers a Jquery event for posting showing a dialog first and on continue it passes on the controller and action.
That works fine. Here is the jquery code:

```
  $('#deleteMaintor-dialog').dialog({
      autoOpen: false, width: 400, resizable: false, modal: true, //Dialog options
      buttons: {
        "Continue": function () {
          $('#aniWait').show();
          $.post(deleteLinkObj[0].href, function (data) {  //Post to action

          $('#Tor').html(data);
          $('#aniWait').hide();
        });
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      "Cancel": function () {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '#btnDeleteMaintor', function (e) {
  deleteLinkObj = $(this);  //for future use
  $('#deleteMaintor-dialog').dialog('open');
  return false; // prevents the default behaviour
});
```

The problem is that after this, none of the jquery events on the controles are fired anymore.

Why not?

I guess this has to do with the Success part of the $.Post?

Comment: usually things freeze after some javascript error that is not handled, are there any errors when you open the browser inspector?

Comment: Nope, no errors. But I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

All the controls that were not working anymore were not anchored to the document, so I did that and now it is working fine.